# undefined method `each' for #<User:0x00007f606007d3a8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

este es mi controller

```
  def create
    @to_do = ToDo.new(to_do_params)
    @to_do.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @to_do.save
        format.html { redirect_to @to_do, notice: 'To do was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @to_do }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @to_do.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: bienvenido a S.O. en Español. ¿en qué línea te está arrojando ese error? Agrega a tu pregunta el error completo. En general ese error es porque estás tratando de iterar sobre un objeto no iterable, en este caso tu modelo de usuario. En el código que pusiste no se ve que estés haciendo un `.each`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!